# How to subtract range from last non empty cell to first?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am a beginner in google sheets and I couldn't get around this formula. I have range of cells and I want to subtract last non empty cell to first cell (Z-A), here is the image:

[image: Subtract values]

As the values are updated in columns C, D, E and so on. I want to get the last non empty cell (from right) and subtract the values by moving backward (left). Like this:

```
sub = 10(Column G)-0(Column F)-10(Column E)-0(Column D)-10(Column C)
```

Can we devise a formula which will get the last non empty cell and subtract values until the first value? Here is the [link to the sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qFg-h7FI70xqL_rVmB0mALIV-JiLuR0cz3CrtxLHIjI/edit#gid=0) Thank you

Comment: Would you mind if I provide you with a custom function using Google Apps Script instead of a sheet formula for this scenario?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 added sample sheet at the end of question description

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(C2:F2<>"")), C2:F2)-(SUM(C2:F2)-
 LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(C2:F2<>"")), C2:F2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works for every condition, just a small request, can we make the range generic, instead of going from `C2:F2` only, can we do 'C2:2'? so that it can work for the whole row.

Comment: @Sohaib435 yes you can use `=LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(C2:2<>"")), C2:2)-(SUM(C2:2)-
 LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(C2:2<>"")), C2:2))` but then formula needs to be in A or B column

Comment: I guess equally =2*LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(C3:F3<>"")), C3:F3)-SUM(C3:F3) but a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion: Use a custom function

You may use the following script as a custom function to get the difference between the value of the last cell and the sum of the other cells:

```
function SUBTRACTFROMLASTNUMBER(data) { //you can rename the custom function name
  var sum = 0;
  var data2 = data[0].filter(x => {
    return (x != "") ? x : null;
  }); //filtered data
  var lastNumber = data2.pop(); //last number
  data2.map(x => sum += x); //sums the remaining values
  return (lastNumber - sum); //returns the output
}
```

This custom function extracts the selected data from the sheet and then separates the value of the last cell using `pop()` and then filters and sums the remaining data using `filter()` and `map()` and then subtracts the sum from the value of the last cell.

### Usage

You may use this function as:

`=SUBTRACTFROMLASTNUMBER(<range>)`
[image]

### Reference:

- [How to Manipulate Arrays in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manipulating-arrays-in-javascript/)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, it almost works but there is one limitation I believe, I gave the whole row in this formula `=SUBTRACTFROMLASTNUMBER(C5:5)`, but if Column C = 10, Column D=0, and Column E=10, then starting from `last column (E)` output should be `(10-0-10=0)`  but it gives `-20` as an output.

Comment: My bad, I just realized that I used the `pop` first before `filter` which will technically get a blank value if the last cell is blank. Let me fix this in a bit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Updated the custom function.

Comment: Column C = 10, Column D = 0, result should be 0-10=-10, but is giving `10` as an output

Comment: Again, I apologize. This time, I have added a conditional statement wherein a zero value is not filtered out and can be considered as the last number. Thank you for your patience. Again, feel free to ask if there are other concerns.